A possibly animated 70s (kids?) TV show about children fleeing from giant creatures/insects into a greenhouse
This one has been bouncing around in my brain for sooo long. I recall only one scene, but hopefully it's specific enough that someone will remember.
It was only a few seconds, but it involved a group of people, mostly kids, I think, running from some large creature(s). I want to say it was giant insects, because I think they ran into a greenhouse to hide. I recall them being surrounded by plants while trying to figure out what they were going to do next.
I'm about 75% sure it was animated, but I can no longer be sure. This would have been approximately 40 years ago, which would have been in the 80s, but for some reason I had the vague notion that it was "old" even back then, so there may be a chance that it originated in the 70s.

Honey, I Shrank the Kids title sequence; https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=npXZd86fNY8?

Were the insects giant, or were the people small? What size were the people in relation to the greenhouse? Were they Earth insects or did they look alien?

@Valorum Impressive guess, but that definitely wasn't it. This was much less.......stylized? The characters, if they were in fact animated, were more lifelike.

@Arletta I wish I could tell you but my memory fails me. The people being small actually feels like a possibility, now that you mention it, but I can't be certain.  =(

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dr._Shrinker , maybe.

@amonroejj That doesn't ring a bell, but that's an amazing guess.  0_o
I'm leaning more toward animated I think, but more like that old LotR movie, where the characters were "realistic" in their appearance and mvoements.
